# Elapsed days between a date and now

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

With:

```
var s = '2016/04/22';
```

how can I count the number of elapsed days between `Date.now()` and `s`?

Of course,

```
Date.now() - s;
```

won't work. I know how to do this in many languages (e.g. in Python which has many libraries for date time manipulation), but in JavaScript, I can't find a built-in solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you should be able to convert the string to a `Date` simply using the Date constructor.

```
new Date('2016/04/22') // Fri Apr 22 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

You can also use `Date.parse` if you need milliseconds instead of a date object:

```
Date.parse('2016/04/22') // 1461276000000
```

In order to count number of days first start by calculating elapsed milliseconds and then divide it by the number of milliseconds in a day:

```
const MILLISECONDS_IN_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
const elapsedDays = (Date.now() - Date.parse('2016/04/22')) / MILLISECONDS_IN_DAY;
```

Comment: You *could* use the Date constructor (or Date.parse, they are equivalent for parsing), but it is not recommended. Given the inconsistencies of native parsing, it is much safer to manually parse strings, either with a library or simple parse function.

Answer (score 2):

you convert s to a Date first:

```
var s= '2016/04/22';
var ymd=s.split('/')
var dt=new Date(ymd[0],ymd[1]-1,ymd[2])
Math.round((Date.now().setHours(0,0,0,0)-dt)/(1000*60*60*24))
```

as suggest by @RobG, you avoid timezone `DST` issues with `setHours(0,0,0,0)`:

```
var s= '2016/04/22';
var ymd=s.split('/');
var dt=new Date(ymd[0],ymd[1]-1,ymd[2]);
var now=new Date();
now.setHours(0,0,0,0);
Math.round((now-dt)/(1000*60*60*24))
```

you may also prefere to use nother rounding like `Math.floor` instead of `Math.round`

Comment: It may suit better to set the time for "now" to zero first, so `(new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0) - dt)`. Of course that is only if an "elapsed" day is based on dates and 2016-04-20T23:59:59 to 2016-04-21T00:00:01 is one day . +1 for parsing the string manually.

Answer (score 1):

As you observed, JavaScript built-in support for date manipulation is *very* limited. In case you do it frequently, you may want to consider [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) library

Comment: This is not an answer, it should be a comment.

Answer (score 1):

two little utilities

```
var day = v => Math.floor(v/86400000);
var now = Date.now || (()=>+new Date);
```

and the code

```
var time = Date.parse('2016/04/22');    
day(now()) - day(time);
```

Comment: Given that the *now* function requires support for ECMAScript 2015 arrow functions, what implementation would support that and not have *Date.now* from the previous version of ECMAScript (ES5)? And why have 6 function calls when `Math.floor((Date.now - Date.parse('2016/04/22'))/8.64e7)` achieves exactly the same result in 3 (noting that the use of *Date.parse* is strongly discouraged) and is less to type.